# Flask pagination iter pages preveneting SQL injection and adding next-page button in HTML template

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, sql-injection

I'm trying to create a button in my HTML that will go to the next/previous page when the button is clicked. I've tried pagination and peewee but didn't seem to get it to work.

Here is my app:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, json
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'example'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'fund_raiser'
mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/funds/pages/', defaults={'page':0})
@app.route('/funds/pages/<int:page>')
def fund_pages(page):
    perpage = 5
    first_page = page*perpage
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from fund_table limit "+str(first_page)+", "+str(perpage)+";", mysql.connection.commit())
    data = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('funds.html', data=data)
```

Where do I add the href tag in my html page? What is the correct variable to use?

Moreover, is my code vulnerable to SQL injection in this line, if so how do i fix:

```
cur.execute("select * from fund_table limit "+str(first_page)+", "+str(perpage)+";", mysql.connection.commit())
```

Comment: You should not ask 2 questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're only accepting int as your user input, the risk of an SQL injection is greatly reduced - converting it to string later is not an issue. I would call this safe already, because the route will throw an error if it receives something that isn't an int after /funds/pages/

However, if you want to use prepared statements (the recommended "secure" method), you should change your execution to

```
cur.execute("select * from fund_table limit %s, %s;", params=(first_page, perpage), mysql.connection.commit())
```

Sending the query parameters separately not only prevents sql-injection, but also increases performance because the overall structure of the query is pre-defined. You should definitely use this as soon as you're accepting anything other than ints for paging.

Can't really answer your first question because there is no code provided

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your code didn't work for me, but this worked:
    cur.execute("select * from fund_table limit %s, %s;" % (first_page, perpage), mysql.connection.commit())

Comment: Sorry for not testing my code, but there is a significant difference here. Modifying the querystring using string formatting does NOT prevent sql injection, it is virtually the same as injecting it as "+first_page+". Please follow the structure here to be safe https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Why the scare quotes around secure?

Comment: because you might still accidentally execute the literal query after logging it for example. using secure without quotes is saying it is 100% secure, which it never is.